# TypeError: type CombinedExpression doesn't define __round__ method

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, orm, rounding

I'm using the ipython (Python 3.7) console in PyCharm.  I'm trying got run a Django ORM query where I want to do some date math specifically calculating number of seconds and comparing that to another field.  I tried

```
Article.objects.filter(article_stat__elapsed_time_in_seconds=(round(datetime.now(timezone.utc) - F("created_on")) / 300) * 300)
```

but I'm getting the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/mainpage_project/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3267, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-18-607b95229a28>", line 1, in <module>
    Article.objects.filter(article_stat__elapsed_time_in_seconds=(round(datetime.now(timezone.utc) - F("created_on")) / 300) * 300)
TypeError: type CombinedExpression doesn't define __round__ method
```

Here is the model in question ...

```
class Article(models.Model):
    ...
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
```

How do I overcome this "TypeError: type CombinedExpression doesn't define **round** method" error?

Comment: What database are you using? You are mixing Python code (rounding) with Django's way of spelling out **SQL** filters. The `datetime.now(timezone.utc) - F("created_on")` expression is turned into a SQL `WHERE` filter, rounding has to happen *at that level*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`datetime.now(timezone.utc) - F("created_on")` is a combined expression; you can't pass that to the Python `round()` function, there is no concrete number to round here, and you'd want the rounding to happen at the database level anyway.

If we assume that you are connecting to a database that implements a `ROUND` function, then you can use a [`Func()` expression](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/expressions/#func-expressions) to express that in a Django filter:

```
from django.db.models import F, Func

time_filter = (
    Func(
        datetime.now(timezone.utc) - F("created_on"),
        function='ROUND'
    ) / 300) * 300
Article.objects.filter(article_stat__elapsed_time_in_seconds=time_filter)
```

Comment: Thanks.  I'm using PostGres 9.5.  I'm getting a "HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts." after implementing your logic, but I think that's more a problem with my tryhing to use Postgres' ROUND with date subtraction.  I'm going to go research that and then I'll come back and accept.